# Python time formatting and plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, anaconda

I have a dataset that has columns having the date in the following format: 2021-05-31T08:00:00+07:00. One column represents eta(expected time of arrival) and the other represents etd(expected time of departure). I want to plot these two columns against each other in python to get an understanding of how much delay is observed in time. In other words, I want to observe how much change is there between eta and etd. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the date is still in string format, first you need to convert both eta and etd to datetime format by using **pd.to_datetime**

```
import datetime
df['eta'] = pd.to_datetime(df['eta'])
df['etd'] = pd.to_datetime(df['etd'])
```

Then add new delay column

```
df['delay'] = df['eta] - df['etd']
```

The result is in timedelta

For example

```
etd, eta = '2021-05-31T08:00+07:00', '2021-05-31T08:30+07:00'
etd, eta = pd.to_datetime(etd), pd.to_datetime(eta)
delay = eta-etd
```

*Result :*
Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00')

This is how I handle this kind of situation, I'm still new so if there is any other way / more efficient way please let me know